# Getting WA for SPOJ smpseq

Tags: c++

Here is the link to the question: http://www.spoj.com/problems/SMPSEQ3/

I am getting WA every time although the code works for all of the test cases I have tried

Please give me a hint.I am a beginner in this

This is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    bool check;
    int cnt=0;
    cin >> n;
    int s[n];
    int c[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> s[i];

    cin >> m;
    int q[m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        cin >> q[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        check = false;
        int j = 0;

            while(q[j] <= s[i])
            {

                if(q[j] == s[i])
                    check = true;
                j++;
            }

            if(check == false)
            {
                c[cnt] = s[i];
                cnt++;
            }

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        cout << c[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Printing extra space and not printing newline character may not be good for online judges.

Comment: @MikeCAT extra space where? and where should I print the newline character? I don't think I need to.I am getting the output just as it is shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

You code fails because you do not keep a check on the value of `j` whether it is less than `m` or not, you simply keep on incrementing it until you hit a value where `q[j] <= s[i]`. So, when your `j` becomes `m` in the `while` loop, you are actually accessing memory which was not allocated to you, and there is some garbage value stored there. Since the garbage value can be anything you might eventually miss some values in `q[]` which should be added to `c[]`.

So, your `while` condition shall look like this ::

```
while(j < m && q[j] <= s[i])
```

I think this shall give you an AC.

A few more things you initialize `j = 0` every time you enter the `for` loop, which is useless. Since in the question it is given that both the sequences are sorted, so considering the sequences ::

> S = a, b, c, d . . .
>
> Q = aa, bb, cc, dd . . .

So, considering if `aa < a` but `bb > a` so, in the first iteration your `j` stops at `bb`. So, now when `i` comes at `b` in `S`, since `a > aa` and `b >= a`(S is a sorted sequence), so `b > aa` as well. So, you do not need to initialize `j = 0` at the beginning of every iteration, which will save you wasteful computations. You just need to initialize `j = 0` at beginning of the `main`.

Moreover, you do not need to save the result in a new array, you can simply print it, when you encounter `check == false`, this save you some space.